# Problem in updateing dpkg version 1.19.0 to newest version

Tags: 18.04, dpkg

I installed ubuntu 18.04 and i have dpkg version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).

```
 dpkg --version
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
```

I want to update or upgrade dpkg to one of 1.18.26، 1.19.8، 1.20.10، 1.21.8 versions.
i run `aptitude upgrade dpkg`

```
dpkg is already installed at the latest version (1.19.0.5ubuntu2.4), so it will not be upgraded
The following packages will be REMOVED:
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Why do you want this? Ubuntu versions are different. You can't upgrade to a non-Ubuntu package this way. But trying to upgrade it another way will break the system.

Comment: @Pilot6 for more security

Comment: Can you elaborate? Ubuntu versions get security updates. But versions are different. So a short answer is: don't do it, it makes no sense.

Comment: If you are concerned about a specific CVE, please add it to your question. You can always check if it is fixed in the Ubuntu package. I bet it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has different package version numbers compared to upstream versions.

But Ubuntu packages get security updates. If you read somewhere that in e.g. version `1.19.8` some security vulnerability has been fixes, it doesn't mean that you need exactly that version in Ubuntu. You just need to keep your system updated.

For example the `1.19.0.5ubuntu2.4` `dpkg` version has the latest security fix, the same as in the upstream `1.19.8`.

```
dpkg (1.19.0.5ubuntu2.4) bionic-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: Directory traversal issue in dpkg-source
    - scripts/Dpkg/Source/Archive.pm, scripts/t/Dpkg_Source_Archive.t:
      Prevent directory traversal for in-place extracts.
    - CVE-2022-1664

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Wed, 25 May 2022 07:14:56 -0400
```

Compare to the upstream:

```
dpkg (1.19.8) buster-security; urgency=medium

  [ Guillem Jover ]
  * Perl modules:
    - Dpkg::Source::Archive: Prevent directory traversal for in-place extracts.
      Reported by Max Justicz <max@justi.cz>. Fixes CVE-2022-1664.
  * Build system:
    - Build gitlab CI images for buster instead of sid.

  [ Updated man pages translations ]
  * German (Helge Kreutzmann).

 -- Guillem Jover <guillem@debian.org>  Tue, 24 May 2022 13:40:09 +0200
```

So your installed version doesn't need to be updated.